# update database in ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion form that I want to update my database. I am using the record ID, but there's a issue. When I type the url - localhost:8500/elephant_shack/update.cfm?record_id=1 I get to the for, but not with the form. I am a totally newbie and am lost!

Any help would be great :)

```
<!--- form--->
<cfquery name="GetRecordtoUpdate" datasource="elephant_shack">
        SELECT *
         FROM Richard
         WHERE record_id = #URL.record_id#
</cfquery>


<table>
<cfoutput query= "GetRecordtoUpdate">
<form action="update_action.cfm" method="Post">

   <tr>
    <td width="93">record id:</td> 
    <td width="286"><input name="record_id" type="text" value="#record_id#" size="25"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="93">Item:</td> 
    <td width="286"><input name="item" type="text" value="#item#" size="25"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Stock:</td>
    <td><input name="stock" type="text" value="#stock#" size="12"></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Par:</td>
    <td><input name="par" type="text" value="#par#" size="12"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Order:</td>
    <td><input name="order" type="text" value="#order#" size="50"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="Submit" value="Update Information"></td>
</tr>
</form>
    </cfoutput>
</table>
```

Also, the database is not being updated.

```
<!--- update form--->
<cfupdate datasource="elephant_shack" tablename="Richard">
```

Comment: Clarify please.  You say, `When I type the url - localhost:8500/elephant_shack/update.cfm?record_id=1 I get to the for, but not with the form.`  What exactly does, `I get to the for` mean?

Comment: I would suggest not using `cfupdate `. Learn how to write the SQL, to handle this.

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Replace #URL.record_id# with <CFQUERYPARAM VALUE="#URL.record_id#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_NUMERIC">. It's more secure. (2) Verify that the location of the code exists, that is, the page {WEBROOT}/elephant_shack/update.cfm. (3) Verify that the row having that record_id exists in the database. (4) Add validation as follows `<cfif isDefined("form.record_id")><cfupdate datasource="elephant_shack" tablename="Richard"></cfif>`. (5) This code should be on the form's action page, _update_action.cfm_.

Comment: @Dan opps I have a typo I meant to say there form. I want to get the values with the form

Comment: To get the values from the form, you must first submit it.  Also, as mentioned by @BKBK, the code to process the form values should be  on the form's action page, update_action.cfm.

Comment: I have figured out most of it. I pout a edit in the main form, and now the values come into the update.cfm page in the forms, but when I try to change something I get this error:
 
The error occurred in /Applications/ColdFusion2018/cfusion/wwwroot/elephant_shack/update_action.cfm: line 13
11 :        '#FORM.stock#',
12 :        '#FORM.par#',
13 :        '#FORM.order#')
14 :

Comment: I am using SQL to enter the values into the db, as <cfupdate> isn't working.<cfquery datasource="elephant_shack">
INSERT INTO Richard(item,
                    stock,
                    par,
                    order)
 
VALUES('#FORM.item#',
       '#FORM.stock#',
       '#FORM.par#',
       '#FORM.order#')
</cfquery>